# Get top authors for the last 30 days with posts count and avatar

Tags: author, list-authors, multi-author

I want to get top authors for the last 30 days ordered by post-count with their avatar image just like the image:

[image: author data]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Where / how do you want to display it? Or you want to get this information in code?

Comment: I want to get this information in a function. After that, I'll place it where I want.